# Public key authenticating local user when LDAP server is down

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ssh, ldap, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to configure my system to allow me to login (ssh) to a local account on a host (Ubuntu 16.04) with public key authentication, even if/when the LDAP server is down.

This is a cloud image, so the user I need locally is `ubuntu`. This user doesn't have a password (and I don't want to set one for security). Only public key auth should be allowed on this user.

This user has UID `1001` and all my LDAP users have UID numbers >= 2000.

I've been trying stuff all day (such as `pam_succeed_if.so` and `pam_localuser`).

Now `getent passed ubuntu` works fine and returns the local passwd line. But `ssh` refuses like so:

```
Sep  6 17:27:43 ip-10-99-0-241 sshd[24895]: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as (null) - Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  6 17:27:43 ip-10-99-0-241 sshd[24895]: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldap.domain.tld: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  6 17:27:43 ip-10-99-0-241 sshd[24895]: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
```

And then eventually it fails with `Authentication failed.`.

- `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

  ```
  passwd:         compat [success=return] ldap
  group:          compat [success=return] ldap
  shadow:         compat [success=return] ldap
  ```
- `/etc/pam.d/common-account`

  ```
  account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
  # NOTE: These two won't work - fatal: Access denied for user <ldap user> by PAM account configuration [preauth]
  #account sufficient                      pam_localuser.so
  #account sufficient                      pam_succeed_if.so uid [le sign] 500 quiet
  account [success=1 default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]  pam_ldap.so
  account requisite                       pam_deny.so
  account required                        pam_permit.so
  account required                        pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=2000
  ```
- `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

  ```
  auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=2000 ignore_root
  auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
  auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass ignore_unknown_user ignore_authinfo_unavail
  # NOTE: Can't login with this (changed the success above)!
  #auth    requisite                       pam_succeed_if.so uid [ge sign] 500 quiet
  auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
  auth    required                        pam_permit.so
  ```
- `/etc/ldap.conf`

  ```
  bind_timelimit 10
  pam_min_uid 2000
  nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ubuntu,local
  nss_reconnect_tries 2
  nss_reconnect_sleeptime 1
  nss_reconnect_maxsleeptime 8
  nss_reconnect_maxconntries 2
  ```

(I tried using the pre and code blocks, but SOF refused to let me post then, so sorry if this looks horrible - if anyone with admin rights can go in and fix, please do.)

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the [man page for `nsswitch.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html), gave me this:

- `return`

  - Return  a result now.  Do not call any further lookup functions.  However, for compatibility reasons, if this
    is the selected action for the group database and the notfound status, and the configuration  file  does  not
    contain the initgroups line, the next lookup function is always called, without affecting the search result.

Key words here is this part: *the configuration file does not contain the initgroups line, the next lookup function is always called*.

As in, if I added the line

```
initgroups:     files
```

I can now login to the `ubuntu` user, even when the LDAP server is down!